# What is the strength of the single Replacement sentence?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axioms

What's the consistency strength of adding the following single sentence replacement like statement to $\sf Z + \forall x \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$ ?

$$\forall \varphi \forall A \ [\forall x \in A \exists \alpha \forall \theta > \alpha:  V_\theta \models \exists! y \varphi(x,y) \to \\  \exists \beta: \forall x \in A \exists  y \in V_\beta: V_\beta \models \varphi(x,y)]$$

The idea is that $\sf ZF$ is not aximatizable by adding a single sentence to axioms of Zermelo set theory, on the other hand the above statement seems to be a theorem of $\sf ZFC$, so this means that the above theory must be strictly weaker than $\sf ZFC$.

> Which of the known fragments of $\sf ZFC$ this theory would  be equivalent to?

Note: This question has already been asked on MathStackExchange and it is not answered yet.

Comment: Are you assuming that each $V_\alpha$ is a set?

Comment: @HanulJeon, yes, I think this is a theorem of $\sf Z + \forall x \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$, since the indices are von Neumann ordinals as usual.

Comment: Do we need replacement to ensure $V_\alpha$ is a set? $\mathsf{Z}$ lacks replacement (especially, $\Pi_1$-replacement), so I am skeptical about $\mathsf{Z}$ proves $V_\alpha$ exists for all $\alpha$.

Comment: @HanulJeon, $\sf Z$ alone doesn't prove that of course, I mean $\sf Z + \forall x \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$ can prove it